# How to remove the color again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Its a favorite stat, so i want to remove the color when i click star again to display:none

```
//js

function addRating(obj) {
    $('li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('#rating').val((index+1));
        if(index == $("li").index(obj)) {
            return false;   
        }
    });
}

function resetRating() {
    if($("#rating").val()) {
        $('li').each(function(index) {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            if((index+1) == $("#rating").val()) {
                return false;   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/razanrab/7YjPu/41/

Comment: *"i want to remove the color when i click star again to display:none"* which is it? you want to remove the color when you click again OR you want the star to be hidden with `display: none`?

Comment: If you want to remove the color when you click it again, use `$.toggleClass()` instead of `$.addClass()` - http://jsfiddle.net/7YjPu/42/ is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: you have to events running on the same element

Comment: @MichaelCoker that won't work event is going to bubble.

Comment: @MichaelCoker yes thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a click event as it is much more standard in jQuery. I also added cursor:hover to your CSS to make it look better.  Additionally, I changed it to class star that way it will work properly with more than one star

```js
$(".star").on("click",function() {
  obj=this;
  $('#rating').val($("li").index(obj));
  $('li').removeClass("selected").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    if(index == $("li").index(obj)) {
      return false; 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li{display: inline-block;color: #F0F0F0;text-shadow: 0 0 1px #666666;font-size:30px;cursor:pointer}
.highlight, .selected {color:#F4B30A;text-shadow: 0 0 1px #F48F0A;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="detailsPage" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
   <a href="index.html" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn  ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-back"></a>
   <h1 id="Name"></h1>
  </div>
 <div data-role="content">
  <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating" />
   <ul>
      <li  class="star">★</li>
      <li  class="star">★</li>
      <li  class="star">★</li>
         
   </ul>
  </div>  
     </div>
```